# Who does the search for `getProgramAccounts()` call?

Tags: performance, getprogramaccounts, scalability

Do the RPC nodes do the search or do they distribute it to the validator nodes?
If it is RPC nodes, do they have to store the entire ledger to do this?

Comment: `do they have to store the entire ledger to do this?` is a separate question

Comment: They store the entire current state just like a validator.

Comment: it would be helpful to elaborate this question with more details, such as motivation, examples, unexpected observations, etc. "elaborating" a question with more questions tends to imply a lack of focus and the need for deeper consideration on what the true question should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RPC node is essentially a non-votung validator.

They have the entire current account state stored in memory on them, and use that account state to search when `getProgramAccounts` is used.